# PHP strings have same encoding (UTF8) and appear as identical in browser but are not equal

Tags: php, string, curl, utf-8, comparison

so I need to compare to strings (1 is a result from a CURL call to a remote URL, using charset UTF8) and the other is hardcoded in my script (utf8 as well).
The strings look the same but when I compare them using strcmp(), the result is -44.
I tried to trim() both of them, but still same result.

I double checked their encoding us mb_detect_encoding() and they appear to be both in UTF8 (as I expect them to be).

I also double check them with preg_match('!!u', $string) which seems to be an accurate way to detect if they are in UTF8 as well. result is 1, so they both are.

**bin2hex(string1)**
h**ps://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=h**p://www.topito.com/top-images-monde-chats-connards-de-felins

> 68747470733a2f2f67726170682e66616365626f6f6b2e636f6d2f76322e332f3f69643d3c6c696e‌6b3e687474703a2f2f7777772e746f7069746f2e636f6d2f746f702d696d616765732d6d6f6e64652‌d63686174732d636f6e6e617264732d64652d66656c696e733c2f6c696e6b3e

**bin2hex(string2)**
h**ps://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=h**p://www.topito.com/top-images-monde-chats-connards-de-felins

> 68747470733a2f2f67726170682e66616365626f6f6b2e636f6d2f76322e332f3f69643d68747470‌3a2f2f7777772e746f7069746f2e636f6d2f746f702d696d616765732d6d6f6e64652d63686174732‌​d636f6e6e617264732d64652d66656c696e73

How can I make them equal ? I tried to convert them both to utf8 (from utf8 ^^) using mb_convert_encoding(), but still they are not equal....

Thank you

**EDIT**
i'm extracting my string(which are URL) using cURL from this feed: h**p://www.topito.com/feed

my curl function is:

```
  $header[] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100";
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; // Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
  $header[] = ""; 

  $curl = curl_init ();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.fr");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd().'/cookies.txt');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd().'/cookies.txt');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $html = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close ( $curl );
```

Comment: yes I can see they are different, but hwo do i make them identical ?

Comment: also print the string contents for string1 and string2 ( can just echo them ) and add this to the post

Comment: How do you retrieve the string from your curl call? try decoding yours and compare it to the curl one, it might be iso for some weird reason.

Comment: UTF-8 allows multiple representations of the same letters, like e.g. composed and decomposed variants. Further, if you have zero-width spaces anywhere, those will render invisibly but still change the string content. In order to find out, extract just the differing parts and determine their Unicode codepoints.

Comment: Use the [Normalizer](http://php.net/manual/de/normalizer.normalize.php) on both strings and see if they are still different.

Comment: @TimPietzcker with normalizer_normalize() they are also different

Comment: string1: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=<link>http://www.topito.com/top-images-monde-chats-connards-de-felins</link><br />`

string2: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=http://www.topito.com/top-images-monde-chats-connards-de-felins`.  need to remove the <link> and <br /> at a minimum

Comment: BTW: Don't blindly believe `mb_detect_encoding()`! This function only makes an educated guess what the encoding could be and there are cases that this guess is simply wrong. You should **know** the encoding from the API documentation and then perhaps use `mb_check_encoding()` to verify it.

Comment: @amdixon yes !!! the strings are actually totally different due to HTML code and I didnt spot it !! So shameful ! it's corrected and now working fine. Thank you

Comment: nw - it helps to paste the strings into notepad on different lines for this purpose ( and to put these contents into the question )

Comment: @amdixon, I credited maalls as his answer also give me a clue, but You helped me a lot and gave me the final solution, is there a way I can share the credit of answer to you ? or upvote you ?

Comment: @Cyriltra ive added a process-based answer for this ( feel free to upvote ;)

Comment: @amdixon I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the HTML source code of what you copy pasted here, they are not the same. The second string  has an additional entities & # 8203 ; (check the second `‌​')

http://pasteboard.co/wBd2Ea4.png

Comment: yes correct, I realized the strings are actually very different due to html tag included but not rendering in my browser :( thank you